# Launching with debugger attached causes android app to hang. BadPacketException in EventLog

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, adb, android-debug

After updating Android Studio to version 4.1 and the Android emulator to version 30.1.5-6855416, I'm having trouble debugging in the emulator.

After stopping the emulator, wiping its data, and then cold booting, I can sometimes successfully debug the app, but never more than once.  When it works, the debugger attaches and I receive output in the debug console.  When it doesn't work, or if I end the debugger session (by pressing the red square "stop" button) and try to debug a second time,  I'll see one of two things:

1. the debugger fails to attach, and the app hangs endlessly with the `waiting for debugger to attach` message, while the debugger console prints `Waiting for application to come online` repeatedly until finally giving up with `Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.`
2. The app will start (the "waiting for debugger" popup goes away) and I get a few of the normally expected log messages in the console, but then the app hangs at a blank white screen, and my log statements stop, both in the debug console, and in logcat.

I will continue to get this result, even if I restart the emulator, restart adb-server, or activate developer mode on the device and disable and re-enable USB debugging.  The only way I've found to be able to get the debugger to connect is to shut down the emulator, wipe data in avd manager, and cold boot it.

If I start the app without the debugger (by clicking its icon in the emulator) then the app starts up fine, and I can return to Android Studio and attach the debugger to the already running process, and hit breakpoints. I can repeat this more than once.  There is no output to the debug console with this method, however it does show up in logcat.

What is causing this, and how can I restore the ability to launch my app with the debugger attached?

[UPDATE]: I am now starting to find that even after wiping data and cold-booting, I cannot start the app with debugger attached anymore.

I've seen the following in the Event Log, not sure if it's related:

```
12:20 AM    null
                com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.chunkhandler.BadPacketException
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.chunkhandler.JdwpPacket.findPacket(JdwpPacket.java:266)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.ClientImpl.getJdwpPacket(ClientImpl.java:696)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:209)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:159)
                

12:20 AM    null
                com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.chunkhandler.BadPacketException
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.chunkhandler.JdwpPacket.findPacket(JdwpPacket.java:266)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.ClientImpl.getJdwpPacket(ClientImpl.java:696)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:209)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:159)
                

12:20 AM    null
                java.nio.BufferOverflowException
                at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:206)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.chunkhandler.JdwpPacket.move(JdwpPacket.java:192)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.Debugger.send(Debugger.java:443)
                at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.incoming(JdwpAgent.java:89)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:205)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:159)
                

12:20 AM    Exception during activity from Selector.

12:20 AM    null
                java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
                at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
                at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.readyOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:87)
                at java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.isAcceptable(SelectionKey.java:360)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.JdwpProxyServer.runAsServer(JdwpProxyServer.java:241)
                at com.android.ddmlib.internal.jdwp.JdwpProxyServer.run(JdwpProxyServer.java:273)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[Update 2020/10/28] After various attempts to downgrade individual pieces of my Android setup, I was finally able to restore my ability to debug by deleting my avds and uninstalling the emulator, HAXM, and Android Studio itself (v4.1).  Then I did the following:

- replaced the "platform tools" tools folder in my SDK folder with version 29.0.6
- installed Android Studio 4.0.2
- uninstalled Android SDK platform R  installed the emulator, then
- replaced the "emulator" folder in my SDK folder with v29.3.2
- updated my project's build.gradle file to use build tools 4.0.2
- Created a new avd for API29

Comment: could you try to switch registry "debugger.jb.jdi" off in Android Studio (use find action - regsitry)